# "accessNotConfigured" error occurred using Youtube API v3

Tags: ios, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been struggled with Youtube API and now I am stuck.

What I did is:

1. create a project at google developers console(https://console.developers.google.com)
2. enabled "YouTube Data API v3"
   [image]
3. generate api key of iOS.
   [image]
4. access to https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API KEY}&part=id&q=soccer by web browser and got the error message
   [image]

Am I missing something?
I have read many questions but I cannot solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

In step 3 "generate API key for IOS", the comment on the Google Developer Console web page says

```
Use of this key does not require any user action or consent, does not grant access 
to any account information, and is not used for authorization.
```

Clicking on the *Learn More" button, it says:

```
 Use an API key when your application is running on a server and accessing one of the following kinds of data:
•Data that the data owner has identified as public, such as a public calendar or blog.
•Data that is owned by a Google service such as Google Maps or Google Translate. (Access limitations may apply.)
```

I think you need to use the OAuth process rather than the API Key. Click on *Learn More* in the OAuth section of the Developer Console web page to learn about using OAuth with Apple iOS.

To create oAuth credentials for iOS:

```
Create new Client ID / Installed Application / iOS
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been trying to do it but I have another problem now. please wait a bit more.

Comment: Any solution, tmrex7? It's 2019, and still buggy. Not working with API key, not working with Oauth. Shame...

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds a bit elementary, but I solved this same problem by going back into Google developer, creating a whole new project, new API key, and then it worked. Google quirk??

Comment: You may be hitting the case where your [API access was disabled after 90 days of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794029/396967).