# YouTube Data API returns "Access Not Configured" error, although it is enabled

Tags: youtube-data-api

My internally used web solution to retrieve YouTube video statistics that is based on this example (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/js) now fails to work. Not sure when exactly it happened, but it used to work couple of months ago.

I now tried to run unedited example code (apart from adjusting the CLIENT_ID, of course), and I am getting exactly the same error:

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 123 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123" }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 123 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=123 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."  
}
```

When I check the YouTube API in developer console, it shows enabled status, and the Credentials compatible with this API include the ID used to authenticate the client. I can see the statistics for credential use increment when I retry the API call attempts, and the metrics reflect the number of requests and also show that the error rate is 100%. But there is no extra info on those failed attempts in the console to help on debugging the problem.

I have deleted and recreated API key and OAuth key, but that did not change anything.

Had there been any extra info on those errors on the developer console side, for example client quote exceeded, I could see how to fix this. Now I am completely stuck.

Comment: I have the same problem with subscriptions.list part of the API.

Comment: ive the same error with upload videos

Answer (score 5):

**Create a new project**

Weirdly, creating a new project just gets the API to work properly!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is unfortunately a red herring: your project's access to YouTube Data API Services is [automatically disabled after a 90 day inactivity period](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#d.-accessing-youtube-api-services).

You should have received a notice via email regarding this action, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain access: please fill out and submit the [exceptions form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en).

Comment: I deleted and created a new project and it worked. Disabling and re-enabling the API and the keys was not enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start a new Project with new oAuthCliedID & oAuthClientSecret

Answer (score 0):

What seems to have done it for me after a lot of fiddling was to:

1. Go to the `OAuth consent screen` of the project.
2. Enter an `Application name`.
3. Press `Save`.

Lo and behold, after 5 minutes it started working.

Comment: I think you were seeing a different issue. This will not help if your API access has been disabled.